# Data insertion obviously works, but is not showing up on table

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am trying to insert data into my database table using the insert statement as shown below:

```
private void buttonPurchase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (MessageBox.Show("Purchase?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes) {

    ////store invoice
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
    ["CarDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[invoiceTbl] ([invoiceId], [dateAndTime]) VALUES (2, N'2014-06-22 00:00:00')";
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
    sqlConnection1.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlConnection1.Close();
}
```

but although no errors were shown, the code works, the data inserted is not showing up in my table data. I tried adding them manually in the table, and copied the sql statement directly into the code shown above, when I add in duplicate data it is detected, but when I add in data again (without duplicating the primary key) the table data shows NULL and NULL respectively. So in short I think my code works, but for some weird reason it just doesn't show up in my schema! Any help is deeply appreciated! :)

Comment: How are you quering the table?

Comment: @Horaciux sorry I don't quite get what you mean! I have a table with two columns namely invoiceId and dateAndTime! Thus when I execute the code above new rows are not created :(

Comment: There are possible scenarios where rows are added but querying through a view -e.g.- don't show them.